# install multiple jar files in local maven repository

Tags: java, maven

i know that if you have a jar file and u want to use it in your local maven repository 
first you need to go to your maven repository and install it by following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> 
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

but in this way i have to install jar files one by one , what if i have lots of jar files 
do i have to type this command several times, isn`t there another solution??

Comment: Are they 3rd party jars?

Comment: yes i mean i wrote them and created jar files may self

Comment: In this case using repository manager like Archiva, Nexus can make life easier.

Comment: If they're your jars, not 3rd party ones, then why don't you just do a `mvn deploy` when you build each of them?

Comment: but isn`t there any other add-hoc solutions, for examples using wildcard characters or something!

Comment: maven deploy! ok as far as i know this command deploys your maven created projects to an specified location {in this case local repository} but what if i have created may jars in the past and at the moment i am left with a bunch of jar files!

Comment: `deploy` puts the artifact into a remote repository where your whole team can access it, `install` puts the artifact into a local repository where only you can access it.  If I was moving to Maven, which I assume you're doing, I'd be tempted to move all the projects over in one hit and simply deploy each as I went.  At the end of the day, each artifact needs a unique artifact id, so you're going to have to do them one at a time one way or another

Comment: i guess that is right after all as you said, we need unique artifact id and that cant be auto generated , unless a new maven plugin comes up that can generate these parameters automatically (for example by viewing the contents of the jar file) and automatically installs them in local repo or deploy them to remote repo

Comment: If you've got a lot of jars to deploy and are short on time then the alternative to converting each project to Maven would be to just script install/deploy and use the jar name as the artifact id (which is close to what Maven does anyway)

Comment: yes i guess that`s it

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if I did not understand the question, but you can not just make a pom with all inside the jar declared as dependencies?

In this way by installing this pom you will install all the jars at the same time...

Answer (score -2):

Use the below plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifacts>
            <artifact>
              <file>some file</file>
              <type>extension of your file </type>
              <classifier>optional</classifier>
            </artifact>
            ...
          </artifacts>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: yes i think nick is right it is irrelevant can u explain it more